# Bibtex \bibliographystyle{acm} with authors-year in citation

Tags: bibtex, acm, bibliographystyle, authoryear

I would like to use the bibliography style acm with authors' names + year instead of numbers. Is it somewhat possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip} %With this, If I don't need the \\
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper,
          includehead,       
          left={2.2 cm},
          right={2.2 cm},
          top={2.2 cm},
          footnotesep={15 pt},
          headsep={17 pt},
          headheight={1.2 cm}
          ]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10 pt}



\title{Some Title% 
       \\
       \vspace{7pt}
       \normalsize\textbf{PhD Proposal}}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear existing header/footer entries
\fancyhead[L]{\rule[-1.6ex]{0pt}{1.6ex}\scriptsize\textbf{Bulgarelli}: \textit{Market Structure and Sustainability}}
\fancyhead[r]{\footnotesize\thepage}


\maketitle


\section*{Introduction}
Lorem ispum blablabla \cite{ellenmacarthur2022}. 



\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

Bibtex file is:

```
@misc{ellenmacarthur2022, 
 author = {{Ellen MacArthur Foundation}},
 title = {Circular Economy Introduction},
 year = {2022},
 note = {see \url{https://ellenmacarthurfoundation.org/topics/circular-economy-introduction/overview}. Last accessed 02-September-2022}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `acm.bst` is obsolete.  Use `ACM-Reference-Format.bst`. Second, `ACM-Reference-Format` can produce author-year citations if used with `natbib`.

So add to your preamble

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

and put for the bibliography

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{References}
```

and you will get

Lorem ispum blablabla Ellen MacArthur Foundation (2022).